# Reading Redis messages submitted by Celery

Tags: python, flask, redis, celery

I've just started using Celery in a Flask App with a Redis broker and backend. The Redis instance is on AWS. How can I read the messages sent by my app to redis and then received by the celery workers?

Even though i've got it working - i'm not super comfortable with what's really going on. Where can i read more about how the message is published to redis, and how the celery workers read the messages.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [chapter](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#redis) in Celery Monitoring and Management Guide about Redis as a broker. You can use `redis-cli` to inspect the queues and read the messages. Or, you can use [Flower](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#flower-real-time-celery-web-monitor) as a higher-level tool for monitoring.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using Flower and it gave me majority of the information I needed.